# Dividing Scala iterators leads to GCoverhead/JavaHeapSpace problems

Tags: scala, iterator, duplicates, slice, divide

I am processing large data with Scala, so memory and time is an even more important companion than it usually is to me. I am trying to increase the speed of some evaluation by subdividing the initial `Iterator[String]` obtained by `getLines` on a large source file in order to make some subevaluation in parallel and merge the results. I do this by recursively `slice`-ing the iterator into two halfs and recalling the recursive function on each subiterator. 
Now, I am wondering why I get GCoverhead or JavaHeapSpace exception, although the "critical" elements are only evaluated once before the recursion step (in order to get the size of the iterator), but in my opinion not in the recursion step, because `slice` returns an iterator again (which is non-strict by implementation). The following (reduced!) code will fail applied on a ~15g file before concatenating the sublists.

I use `.duplicate`in each step. I looked up the api, the doc of `.duplicate` says "The implementation may allocate temporary storage for elements iterated by one iterator but not yet by the other.", but no element has been iterated yet. Could someone give me a hint what is going wrong there and how to solve this problem? Thank you so much!

```
type itType = Iterator[String]
def src = io.Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines

// recursively divide into equal size blocks in divide&conquer fashion
def getSubItsDC(it: itType, depth: Int = 4) = {
    println("Getting length of file..")
    val totalSize = src.length
    println(totalSize)
    def rec(it_rec: itType = it, depth_rec: Int = depth, size: Int = totalSize): 
        List[itType] = depth_rec match {
            case n if n > 0 => 
                println(n)
                val (it1, it2) = it_rec.duplicate
                val newSize = size/2
                rec(it1 slice (0,newSize), n-1, newSize) ++ 
                    rec(it2 slice (newSize,size), n-1, newSize)
            case n if n == 0 => List(it_rec)
    }
    println("Starting recursion..")
    rec()
}
getSubItsDC(src)
```

In the REPL the code runs equally fast with arbitrary size of iterators (when hard coding the totalSize), thus I assumed correct lazyness.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be better off using the `itr grouped size` to get an `Iterator[Iterator[String]]` (a `GroupedIterator`):

```
scala> val itr = (1 to 100000000).iterator grouped 1000000
itr: Iterator[Int]#GroupedIterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

This will allow you to chunk the processing of parts of your file.

#### Why your solution uses too much memory

Duplicating an `Iterator` is **obviously** an operation which means that the Iterator may have to cache its computed values. For example:

```
scala> val itr = (1 to 100000000).iterator
itr: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> itr filter (_ % 10000000 == 0) foreach println
10000000
....
100000000
```

But when I take a duplicate:

```
scala> val (a, b) = (1 to 100000000).iterator.duplicate
a: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
b: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> a filter (_ % 10000000 == 0) foreach println

//oh dear, garbage collecting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

In this example, as I run through `a`, in order that `b` be a duplicate, the elements that `a` has iterated over *but which `b` has not*, need to be cached

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate! I'm not quite sure how your example of `.duplicate` explains my code problem, because I actually never iterate over any element, am I? I need to consider the use of `.grouped`. I have the feeling this is exactly not what I was looking for, because it returns some kind of Iterator of Lists. My recursive method, in contrast, was intended to return a List of Iterators (so the other way around) so I can call `.par` on that list without any further effort. Grouping first and calling `.toList.par` will cause the same memory crash. Any ideads for that?

Comment: Well, your solution is not tail recursive and uses `Iterator.duplicate`. I'm not sure why an iterator of Lists is exactly not what you're looking for. Is there a Jedi mind trick going on here, perhaps?

Comment: I was aware of no-tail-recursion, but is this the problem? The recursion depth is 4,so this will yield a List of max. size 16 (I hope I'm not wrong there). I use duplicate yes, but I don't evaluate any of the elements, so no caching is needed, how come it still fails? Your example runs for a while, too, so this must mean really only evaluated elements are cached, or am I wrong? I can't use Iterator[List], because I would like to thread on List[Iterator] via `par` without having the sub-iterators being evaluated before. Calling `toList` on the Iterator[List] would load all data into memory.

Comment: Argh okay, I could try `myGroupedIterator.next.par`, let me try that! Sorry.